# Photomultipliers in Parallel

Tags: parallel, photodiode, pulse

I have a photo-multiplier going into a preamp then two stage shaping amp (PC250 and PC275 board from Amptek). The photo-multiplier is attached to a plastic scintillator and then a beta emitting radioactive source is placed atop the scintillator, and the number of output pulses is the source decaying.

My question is, if I put another photo-multiplier and scintillator set up on the other side of the source, and connect the photo-multipliers in parallel, will my count rate double, or stay the same but the pulse amplitude increase?

Thanks!

Comment: By "connect the photo-multipliers in parallel" do you mean connect the outputs of the shaping amplifiers in parallel? Or connect the two photo-multipliers in parallel and connect to a single preamp/amp stage?

Comment: Connect the two photo-multipliers in parallel and connect to a single preamp stage

Answer (score 3):

The photons produced by a 2nd scintillator have nothing in common with the photons produced by the 1st scintillator. Neither will a beta particle emitted on one side of a piece of radio active material have anything in common with a beta particle emitted from the other side.

The average rates from the two photomultipliers will be similar at any point in time and therefore, the combined number of "occurances" will be approximately double.